# JQuery background image slider using images from one of three arrays

Tags: jquery, css, slideshow

Scenario:

- I have a background-image slider.
- JQuery listens for resizing of the window, and depending on the screen size, sets a given array as the source of the image file paths.
- There is a 6 second delay between transitions and it all seems to work fine except I cannot get an image to appear for the first 6 seconds.
- Any efforts so far have resulted in the first image displaying twice, instead of a sequential cycling through of the array.

[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/caseycc/qL3buqdt/12/)

```
$(function(){

var img_41 = "url('https://s33.postimg.org/e11jeeisv/lagoon-467.jpg')",
img_42 = "url('https://s33.postimg.org/68avmepof/christmas-467.jpg')",
img_43 = "url('https://s33.postimg.org/cyrcvu54f/cars-467.jpg')",
img_1 = "url('https://s33.postimg.org/vr37zgr8v/lagoon-720.jpg')",
img_2 = "url('https://s33.postimg.org/mw2doxfb3/christmas-720.jpg)",
img_3  = "url('https://s33.postimg.org/f3bpwyorj/cars-720.jpg')",
img_91 = "url('https://s33.postimg.org/qsfpkxv5r/lagoon-991.jpg')",
img_92 = "url('https://s33.postimg.org/5is3a2rpr/christmas-991.jpg')",
img_93 = "url('https://s33.postimg.org/a4o7ieidr/cars-991.jpg')",
slider1 =[img_1, img_2, img_3],
slider2 =[img_41, img_42, img_43],
slider3 =[img_91, img_92, img_93],
i =0;

var $target = $('.wrapper');
var $win=$(window);
var arr;    

$win.on('resize', function() {
    var screen= $win.width();
    if(screen < 468){
        arr = slider2;  
    }
    else if(screen > 991){
        arr = slider3;  
    }
    else{
        arr = slider1;  
    }

    $target.css({
        'background-repeat':'no-repeat',
        'background-position': 'center center',
        'display':'block'
    });
}).resize();


setInterval(function() {
    $target.animate({ opacity: 0 }, 500, function() {
        console.log(arr[i]);
        $target.css('background-image', arr[i]);
        i++;
        $target.animate({ opacity: 1 }, 500, function() {
            if(i === arr.length) i = 0;
        });
    });
   }, 6000);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fiddle.
You have to make all variables global. Then you create a funtion, that makes the change itself

and then on document.ready, you will call the function and then set the loop

```
/*global variables here*/
        function slide(){
         $target.animate({ opacity: 0 }, 500, function() {
            console.log(arr[i]);
             $target.css('background-image', arr[i]);
             i++;
             $target.animate({ opacity: 1 }, 500, function() {
               if(i === arr.length) i = 0;
             });
           });

        }

     $(function(){
    /*other code here*/
            slide();
            setInterval(function() {
          slide();
        }, 6000);

    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4xs7rm2v/

Comment: Nice simple solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

as I checked you called your image function after 6 seconds. you need to call that animation once before 6 seconds. so it will display first. no waiting till 6 seconds.

Please check this link

[CHECK THIS](https://jsfiddle.net/666z6xd6/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper{height:500px}
```

**jQuery**

$(function(){

```
var img_41 = "url('https://s33.postimg.org/e11jeeisv/lagoon-467.jpg')",
img_42 = "url('https://s33.postimg.org/68avmepof/christmas-467.jpg')",
img_43 = "url('https://s33.postimg.org/cyrcvu54f/cars-467.jpg')",
img_1 = "url('https://s33.postimg.org/vr37zgr8v/lagoon-720.jpg')",
img_2 = "url('https://s33.postimg.org/mw2doxfb3/christmas-720.jpg)",
img_3  = "url('https://s33.postimg.org/f3bpwyorj/cars-720.jpg')",
img_91 = "url('https://s33.postimg.org/qsfpkxv5r/lagoon-991.jpg')",
img_92 = "url('https://s33.postimg.org/5is3a2rpr/christmas-991.jpg')",
img_93 = "url('https://s33.postimg.org/a4o7ieidr/cars-991.jpg')",
slider1 =[img_1, img_2, img_3],
slider2 =[img_41, img_42, img_43],
slider3 =[img_91, img_92, img_93],
i =0;

var $target = $('.wrapper');
var $win=$(window);
var arr;    

$win.on('resize', function() {

        var screen= $win.width();
        if(screen < 468){
            arr = slider2;  
        }
        else if(screen > 991){
            arr = slider3;  
        }
        else{
            arr = slider1;  
        }
        $target.css({
            'background-repeat':'no-repeat',
            'background-position': 'center center',
            'display':'block'
        });
        }).resize();

    rotateImages($target,arr,i)
    setInterval(function() {
    rotateImages($target,arr,i)
  }, 6000);
});

function rotateImages($target,arr,i) {
    $target.animate({ opacity: 0 }, 500, function() {
     $target.css('background-image', arr[i]);
     i++;
     $target.animate({ opacity: 1 }, 500, function() {
       if(i === arr.length) i = 0;
     });
   });
}
```

Hope this will helps you :)

Comment: Thanks for that. The image loaded straight away but did not go through array. Have accepted @Zorak's solution

Comment: @groober That's fine :)